# How to do something upon error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, conditional-statements

Say I do `.operator` on an object and `.operator` produces an error, how can I not have the program terminate and instead do something else.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [Exception Handling](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby provides exception handling via `begin` , `rescue` blocks. you may do the following

```
exception_array = []

begin 
  array.operator
rescue Exception => e
  exception_array << e
ensure
  # this line will execute irrespective of an
  # error happened or not
end
```

Lets breakdown the commands and the program flow

First your program try to execute the command in `begin` block. So if it raise any error, then it goes to `rescue` section

`Exception` is there to catch any type of exception. But you can specify the exception type you want too. Following is the ruby exception hierarchy from [nicksiegers blog](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy/)

```
Exception
    NoMemoryError
    ScriptError
        LoadError
        NotImplementedError
        SyntaxError
    SignalException
        Interrupt
    StandardError
        ArgumentError
        IOError
            EOFError
        IndexError
            StopIteration
        LocalJumpError
        NameError
            NoMethodError
        RangeError
            FloatDomainError
        RegexpError
        RuntimeError
        SecurityError
        SystemCallError
        SystemStackError
        ThreadError
        TypeError
        ZeroDivisionError
    SystemExit
    fatal
```

So depending on the error type you can catch a specific error type if you want to

`=> e` part is assigning your error to a variable called `e`. You can rename this to anything you want.

The last part is `ensure` and this is **optional**, Ensure will execute no matter you get an error or not. So if you have something to get done, if an error happens or not, you can use `ensure`

This is a [good read](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-exceptions-and-exception-handling/) on ruby error handling

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by catching exceptions in `rescue` block.

```
begin
  array.operator
# Change the class according to the Exception you are getting
rescue StandardError => e
  exceptions ||= []
  exceptions << e
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what `rescue StandardError => e` is? How can I make it so that upon error it prints the error as a string to console?

Comment: Based on the hierarchy of errors in ruby, ```StandardError``` represents the lowest level, non-system error you should capture.  You could capture ```Exception``` but that means you'll be capturing things like program terminations which isn't great.  The format above is essentially ```catch (StandardError e)``` from other languages.